# ionic cordova run android always fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am new to ionic and i am trying to run app but the command ionic cordova run android always fails. **please find the detailed exception here**

Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\TECHLAP31\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > com/google/gson/JsonParseException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:11008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > com/google/gson/JsonParseException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:11008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11008) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**here is my ionic info details:**

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1 (C:\Users\TECHLAP31\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.0, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\TECHLAP31\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.0.1
   OS                : Windows 10

**here is installed gradle version details:**

---

### Gradle 4.10

Build time:   2018-08-27 18:35:06 UTC
Revision:     ee3751ed9f2034effc1f0072c2b2ee74b5dce67d

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-3
Kotlin:       1.2.60
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Please help.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: can i please get any help here?